# Pandas groupby() and mean() functions in Python

Tags: python

How can I get the average marks for each student from following dataframe using Pandas groupby() and mean() methods?
The aim is to get the average marks in ascending order of all students.

```
import pandas as pd

# Marks of students in class 4A and 4B
data = {
        'S4A': {
                'Name': ['Amy', 'Mandy', 'Daisy', 'Ben', 'Peter', 'John'],
                'Maths': [99, 87, 88, 70, 88, 76],
                'Chemistry': [89, 90, 90, 90, 89, 82],
                'Physics': [79, 97, 68, 80, 72, 95],
                'English': [90, 65, 56, 67, 86, 82],
                'Biology': [79, 89, 59, 70, 79, 78],
                'History': [75, 81, 78, 55, 68, 84]
               },

       'S4B': {
                'Name': ['Allen', 'Gordon', 'Jimmy', 'Nancy', 'Sammy', 'William'],
                'Maths': [90, 86, 88, 80, 85, 86],
                'Chemistry': [89, 78, 88, 90, 79, 82],
                'Physics': [89, 97, 78, 81, 82, 55],
                'English': [80, 85, 86, 77, 86, 82],
                'Biology': [75, 89, 69, 70, 79, 78],
                'History': [79, 81, 80, 65, 68, 84]
               }
       }

# list of subjects
subjects = ['Maths', 'Chemistry', 'Physics', 'English', 'Biology', 'History']

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Can you refine your example and show what you have tried already? You should include what your expected output is

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dataframe for each class and then compute mean or concat all the classes and compute mean.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data[k]) for k in data], ignore_index=True)
mean_df = df.set_index('Name').mean(1)

print(mean_df)

Name
Amy        85.166667
Mandy      84.833333
Daisy      73.166667
Ben        72.000000
Peter      80.333333
John       82.833333
Allen      83.666667
Gordon     86.000000
Jimmy      81.500000
Nancy      77.166667
Sammy      79.833333
William    77.833333
dtype: float64
```